# continuity of a function defined by an integral ...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

To prove $$f(x)=\int _0 ^ {\infty} \frac{\cos(xt^2)}{1+t^2} dt $$ is continuous for any $x \in R$.

Can't figure out how to estimate $\cos(xt^2)-\cos(x_0t^2)$ so that the integral doesn't diverge. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Maybe you can use that the absolute value of a difference of two cosines is bounded above by 2.

Comment: yes but then we get $f(x)-f(x_0)$ is bounded by a constant... we need that to be as small as we like...

Comment: @zhw. Ok thanks, it seems I figured out. Dominated convergence gives the proof...

Comment: $I = \dfrac\pi2\bigg\{\sin(x)\cdot\bigg[C\bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi x}\bigg) - S\bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi x}\bigg)\bigg] - \cos(x)\cdot\bigg[C\bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi x}\bigg) + S\bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi x}\bigg)-1\bigg]\bigg\}$, where *C* and *S* are the two [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the function $f$ be given by

$$f(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(xt^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt$$

We need to show that given $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a number $\delta>0$ such that

$|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

To that end, let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(x_n)|&=\left|\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(xt^2)-\cos(x_nt^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt\right|\\\\
\end{align}$$

Noting that $\frac{\cos(xt^2)-\cos(x_nt^2)}{1+t^2}\le\frac{2}{1+t^2}$ and $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ is absolutely integrable, then [The Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} |f(x)-f_n(x)|&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(xt^2)-\cos(x_nt^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt\right|\\\\
&=\left|\int_0^{\infty}\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\cos(xt^2)-\cos(x_nt^2)}{1+t^2}\right)\,dt\right|\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

And that completes the proof.

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos (xt^2)-\cos(x_nt^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt$$